# Python error NameError: name '__tablename__' is not defined

Tags: error-handling

I am newbie in Python and i require your help.I have a Mac and use python 3. Work with SublimeText and this is what i receive while running my code==> i received this error:`NameError: name '__tablename__' is not defined`

Thank you in advance!!!

My entire code is:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)


from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()



#creare de tabela

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    program = Column(String)
    aka = Column(String)
    adresa = Column(String)
    city = Column(String)
    state = Column(String)
    country = Column(String)
    postalcode = Column(String)

def __repr__(self):
    return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', program='%s', aka='%s',adresa='%s',city='%s',country='%s',postalcode='%s',)>" %(
        self.name, self.fullname, self.program, self.aka, self.adresa, self.city, self.state, self.country,self.postalcode)

#creare de tabela
User.__tablename__
table('users', MetaData(bind=None),
    Column('id', Integer(),table=(users), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('name', String(), table=(users)),
    Column('fullname', String(), table=(users)),
    Column('program', String(), table=(users)),
    Column('aka', String(), table=(users)),
    Column('adresa', String(), table=(users)),
    Column('city', String(), table=(users)), 
    Column('state', String(), table=(user)),
    Column('country', String(), table=(users)),
    Column('postalcode', String(), table=(users), schema=None))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a ["private variable"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)

> [...] Any identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with `_classname__spam`, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped.

In your usecase, you can access it with `User._user__tablename__`

To avoid this problem, mark your varbaile with *one* leading underscore, and remove the two trailing underscores. This is suggestet by [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles):

> `_single_leading_underscore`: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. from M import * does not import objects whose name starts with an underscore.

Comment: Thanks Tim! i changed the code as per your post, but i receive the same error.

Comment: Does the error comes from the line ```User.__tablename__``` ?